# unable to chown a directory recursiverly "unknown user id"

Tags: chown

I trying to chown the directory for changing the permissions of the directory. But it shows some error as unknown user id

I tried to `chown` using the command : `chown -R www-data [directory name]`

it shows the error as `unknown user id www-data`

How to get rid of this.

Comment: Creating the www-data user...

Comment: I'm guessing you're using a guide for a Debian-based distro which has a www-data user, except you're trying to use the guide on a distro that doesn't have that user. Please point to the guide and tell us what distro you're using.

Comment: yes, you are true. I'm using Debian-based distro, actually this problem occurred in webdesigning in drupal. I couldn't get write permissions for a directory.

Comment: If you're using a Debian-based distro, you should have a `www-data` user. I'd figure out why you don't.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is simple, that user/id doesn't exist:

```
$ chown adsfadsf files
chown: invalid user: ‘adsfadsf’
```

Verify the user exist and try again.

Comment: do you mean I need to check for the user id : www-data ????

Comment: i found it (www-data) some where in the web as it is used to change the user permissions.

Comment: @GIRI I have no idea of what are you doing.... really.